# iTunes on wine suddenly stopped working

Tags: wine, itunes

Around January of 2023, iTunes suddenly returned this error when I try to access my Apple Music. This is from the terminal output of wine

```
CertGetCertificateChain failed with error 0x80090304
```

It then shows me the error message visually in a message box in iTunes saying

```
Temporary Error completing your request. Unknown error -50
```

I have tried everything.

- I tried downgrading from wine 7.0 to wine 6, and wine 5. That gave the same results
- I tried upgrading to wine 8.0.1. That did not fix the issue
- I tried installing iTunes again in a different wine prefix. Same error
- I tried installing iTunes 12.5, 12.6 in 32 bit. That did not fix it
- I tried installing a older version of iTunes all the way down to 12.4. Same results
- I tried grabbing a backup of my hard drive and pulled the working prefix off of my backup. That gave the same error.
- I tried installing DLLs using winetricks and overriding the default wine libraries
- I tried using a VPN (just in case they shadow banned my IP for some reason). Still nothing
- I tried using PlayOnLinux. Same error

I have found other people saying that it is the issue of the SSL library in wine and how iTunes switched to a different authentication system, but they did that years ago so that should not be the issue. To further support that, I was using it for 2 years with no issues. No one has complained in January or even recently that this was an issue. It seems that I am the only one. What can I do to fix this?

I know that there is a web version of iTunes but the API only gives you 64kbps audio. I would really like to get it to work again.

What was working before was version 12.6.1.25 64-bit with no DLL overrides and no workarounds.